# OS X Automator and shell issue

Tags: string, macos, shell, automator

I'm trying to make an automator workflow on OS X which opens the selected images in the finder and opens it with Photoshop

During this, I need to use the Shell and here is my code

```
# create an empty string
a=""
# grab all the files selected in the finder (given by the previous operation)
for f in "$@"
do
# make a concatenation of the strings
    a=$a" $f"
done
# change the spaces " " by backslash+space "\ "
a=${a//$" "/$"\\ "}
# cut the first two characters
a=${a:2}
# make the full sentence
a="open -a Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2015 $a"
printf "$a"
```

The result of the last printf is

```
open -a Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2015 /Users/me/Downloads/image\ test.jpg
```

When I paste it in a shell, it works perfectly, but when I run it by adding

```
$a
```

in my little script, I've this issue (the string is cut)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VsFK.png)

Thanks in advance for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't smash the array into a string. That's the problem. Use the array as-is.

See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for why the stringification is a problem.

So just use:

```
open -a Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2015 "$@"
```